# I want to zip the log files with a desired naming convention using shell script with the log file location as an argument

Tags: linux, shell

File -> zip

Argument -> Log file location

File_name.log -> File_name.log.YYYY-MM-DD.EXECUTIONCOUNT.zip

**Example 1**

*Execution on 24/02/21(DDMMYY)*

*File name -> ABC.log*

Output zip file:

ABC.log.2021-02-24.1.zip -> 1st Execution on 24/02/21(DDMMYY)

ABC.log.2021-02-24.2.zip -> 2nd Execution on 24/02/21(DDMMYY)

ABC.log.2021-02-24.10.zip -> 10th Execution on 24/02/21(DDMMYY)

**Example 2**

*Execution on 25/02/21(DDMMYY)*

*File name -> ABC.log*

Output zip file:

ABC.log.2021-02-25.1.zip -> 1st Execution on 25/02/21(DDMMYY)

ABC.log.2021-02-25.2.zip -> 2nd Execution on 25/02/21(DDMMYY)

Comment: You need to remember the current execution count somewhere. How about to store it in a hidden file `.execution_count`, into the same directory where you have the logfile? Since you need this information per date and filename, you could perhaps make `.execution_count` a hidden directory, and in this a directory for each execution day, and within this a file holding the execution count for each log file?

Comment: The alternative would be parsing the currently zipped files and extracting the necessary information from the file names. I feel that this is more complicated, in particular since you want to do this in POSIX shell only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
zipfile=$(for i in "$1"*"$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")"*.zip;do echo "$i";done | awk -F\. 'END { if ($4=="") { split($0,map,"*");print map[1]"."strftime("%Y-%m-%d")".1.zip"} else { gsub($4,$4+1,$4);OFS=".";print $0 } }')

# Loop through a listing of the zip files based on the passed parameter $1 and the generated date. Pass the output into awk, setting the field delimiter to "." Take the last entry and replace the number before ".zip" (field 4 - $4) with the field + 1 and print the result, reading the result into the variable zipfile. Use this variable in the actual zip command.
# If this is the first execution, split returned output into the array map and use this to generate the file name.

zip "$zipfile" "$1"
```

Comment: This script does not increment the EXECUTIONCOUNT it simply update the file.

Comment: excount=$(for i in "$1"*log*"$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")"*.zip;do echo "$i";done | tail -1)? Why do you need an execution count anyway?

Comment: I've amended the solution to take account of the first execution where there are no existing zip files.

Comment: While running the modified command it is incrementing the year in the file name.

Comment: The 4th full stop delimiter field is the number not the year? It works fine when I run it locally on my system. What version of awk are you using?

Comment: It is 4.0.2 version.

Comment: Yeah. Same version as mine. $1 will represent the argument passed to a script. If you are executing the solution outside of a script, change $1 to something like $file and use $file="ABC"

Comment: I am executing the shell script as:
**./zipScript.sh tmp/a.log**

Comment: OK. Try it now.

Comment: Yes it worked..Thanks.
Will the count will again start with 1 again if it is executed in the next day or any other day?

Comment: Yeah, it will revert to 1 for the next day.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Can you please give a short explanation for this script if possible?

Comment: if you can please give a short explanation then it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: No worries, I've added some more notes in the script comments.